# applicationShouldTerminate and NSURLConnection

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsurlconnection

In my Mac OS X application I'm pushing database to Dropbox, kinda syncing. And when user quits application, I want to upload database before exiting. So I implemented applicationShouldTerminate: where I call syncing method and return NSTerminateLater. 
However, underlying NSURLConnection doesn't work at all - no delegate methods are called, and just nothing happens. All uploading code work well from other places, and even when I return NSTerminateCancel from applicationShouldTerminate:
This happens on Mac OS Lion 10.7/XCode 4.6, if this metter.

So, any comments? Does returning NSTerminateLater changes something in run loop, or somewhere else?

Comment: I already know that I can return NSTerminateCancel, finish my tasks, set some flag in application and call terminate on NSApp.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The documentation states that after returning `NSTerminateLater`, the application will run the main run loop in the `NSModalPanelRunLoopMode` mode until you call `replyToApplicationShouldTerminate:`.

By default `NSURLConnection` objects are not scheduled for the `NSModalPanelRunLoopMode` mode (only for `NSDefaultRunLoopMode`). So the connection is working but the delegate messages are not delivered because the main run loop needs to be in the `NSDefaultRunLoopMode` mode.

This allows Cocoa to suspend the observation of asynchronous tasks while presenting a modal dialog (`NSModalPanelRunLoopMode`) or while tracking mouse-dragging events (`NSEventTrackingRunLoopMode`). Though that behavior may be justified in some case, people tend to agree that modal interfaces are bad juju as they generate intrusion, frustration and [mode errors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mode_%28computer_interface%29#Mode_errors) (hence your problem).

So in order for your `NSURLConnection` to execute correctly, you need to schedule it in the `NSDefaultRunLoopMode` and `NSModalPanelRunLoopMode` modes. This can be achieved with `NSRunLoopCommonModes` which is an alias for all the run loop modes that have been declared as *“common”* (i.e. all the modes used by Cocoa).

```
NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self startImmediately:NO];
[connection scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
[connection start];
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. Unfortunately, quick-changing the stuff you mentioned in the Dropbox SDK doesn't fix the issue. Probably things are a bit more complicated on their side or I didn't change all the places where they create NSURLConnection. Anyway, the main idea was to understand what is going on.

Comment: I'm scheduling my connection in the `currentRunLoop` for the common modes and still not getting delegate callbacks after returning `NSTerminateLater`. Would it make a difference, when the connection is started before or after terminate is called?